# How To Create A Loop To Move To The Next Line

Tags: loops, vbscript, iteration

I'm working with a 3270 terminal mainframe.  I have a screen with 30 positions, in which I need to read from a text file and paste the values in column A into those 30 different positions on the screen.  The text file may have any number of rows, but I only have 30 positions to paste per iteration. After those 30 positions are filled, I click enter, which clears the screen, and I'm able to paste another 30 and so on.  If there is another 30 to paste, there could be less than 30.

There's only one column in the text file (column A). Column A, row 1 of the text file will paste into the 1st position.  Column A, row 2 will paste into the second position and so on...

I've created a loop which reads from my text file and pulls the value into my code, and I am able to paste the value to that first position.  I need to then move to the next row and paste the next value into the next position.  I'm trying to do this without having to create 30 different `Do..Until` loops.

Here is my loop which reads from the text file, this works:

```
Sub sub_Run_Loop
    i = 0
    CountLoans = 0
    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = objFile.ReadLine
        arrFields = Split(strLine, ",")
        subDoWork (i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Sub subDoWork (i)
    ColumnA    = arrFields(0)
    CurrentRow = i
    ActualRow  = CurrentRow - 1

    For CurrentRow = 1 To ActualLoans
        subMoveCursor 13, 4
        subEnterData ColumnA
        CountLoans = CountLoans + 1
    Next
    i = i + 1

    'At Right here, I need to move to the next value in Column A
    'from the text file and paste to the next position

    subMoveCursor 14, 4
    subEnterData ColumnA
    CountLoans = CountLoans + 1

    CountLoans = CountLoans + 1
    If CountLoans >= ActualLoans Then
        subEndScript
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm trying to move from one row to the next while pasting the values in different positions without having to create 30 different loops.

Comment: The easiest way to accomplish this I think would be to simply supply the desired starting line, using a global variable, to the loop and to increase that by the desired number (30 in your case), . In the loop, keep track of the number of lines read, and SkipLine() until you reach the desired one, then read up to the desired number. The downside of this approach would be that you read the file totallines/30 times.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Note: I have Row and Column backwards.  Column is actually row and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.  What I did was set a threshold on the three columns that held the positions I needed to paste to and increased that threshold by 10 (10 rows in each column) after each iteration of 30.  I also re-organized my counts IN THE loop, which appears to have fixed the issue with moving sequentially thru the rows within the three columns.

```
    Sub sub_Run_Loop
       Column1Threshold = 10 
       Column2Threshold = 20
       Column3Threshold = 30
       CountButtonClicks = 0
       ClickTime = 30
       i = 1
       CountLoans = 1
       Column = 13


    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
     strLine = objFile.ReadLine
            arrFields = Split(strLine,",")              
            subDoWork (i)               
    i = i + 1
    CountLoans = CountLoans + 1
    Column = Column + 1     
    If Column > 22 Then 
            Column = 13
    End If

    If CountLoans > ClickTime Then
            subPressKey "@E"
            Column1Threshold = Column1Threshold + 10
            Column2Threshold = Column2Threshold + 10
            Column3Threshold = Column3Threshold + 10
            ClickTime = ClickTime + 30
            CountButtonClicks = CountButtonClicks +1
    End If                  

    If CountLoans > ActualLoans Then
            subEndScript    
    End If
    Loop
 End Sub



Sub subDoWork (i)
    ColumnA     = arrFields(0)
    CurrentRow  = i     

    If CountLoans <= Column1Threshold Then                  
        Row = 4
    End If

    If CountLoans > Column1Threshold Then
        Row = 31
    End If

    If (CountLoans >= Column2Threshold) and (CountLoans <= 
    Column3Threshold) Then
        Row = 58
    End If

    subMoveCursor Column, Row                                                           
    subEnterData ColumnA
End Sub
```